# Perform procedure with hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, groovy

The method to execute a prossidure in the bank was created, but the same is giving this error:
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown parameter registration name [movimentoId]

```
public static void validaPedidoCarga(EntityManager em, String movimentoId){
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder()

        sql.append('BEGIN ')
        sql.append('ADM_SGV.SGV_SFA_PK005.VALIDA_PEDIDO_CARGA(:movimentoId); ')
        sql.append('END;')

        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sql.toString())
        query.setParameter("movimentoId", movimentoId)
        try{
            query.()
            em.close()
        }catch(NoResultException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a procedure is already created into DB then just call that procedure passing the correct argument like,

```
Query query = sf.getCurrentSession()
                .createSQLQuery(
                "CALL Procedure_Name(:movimentoId)")
                .addEntity(ClassName.class)
                .setParameter("movimentoId", "ur_Id");

            List result = query.list();
```